# C++ printing unicode characters gives question marks

Tags: c++, unicode, console

I want to start by saying I know how to print Unicode characters to console using `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)`. The problem I have is with printing Unicode characters that are "non-standard". For example, when I try to print `▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ ▅ ▆ ▇ █ ▇ ▆ ▅ ▄ ▃ ▁` using wprintf, it returns this:

[image: Picture showing output were all but half and full blocks are question marks]

The project is set to "Unicode Character Set" and visual studio is showing the characters fine when showing them from file.

I found the answer and put it below

Comment: I would guess that the characters are not encoded correctly in your string literal.

Comment: BTW there  is no such thing as a non-standard Unicode character. Unicode is a standard. What are the code points for the characters you are trying to print?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for wchar_t?

Comment: @john the code points in hex are `\x2581 \x2582 \x2583 \x2584 \x2585 \x2586 \x2587 \x2588 \x2587 \x2586 \x2585 \x2584 \x2583 \x2582 \x2581`. and I know there isn't a "non-standard" unicode character but it just seemed as if it was characters which are specialized or something like that

Comment: @apetrai I used wstring and also direct print which both use wchar_t

Comment: **1st** do you mean `\u2581 \u2582 \u2583 …` [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) instead of `\x2581 \x2582 \x2583 …`? **2nd** choose another font for your terminal, e.g.  https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code

Comment: yes, I mean `\u` instead of `\x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found so far. there is no easy work around except for using another font which does include those characters. What I ended up doing was just editing the font using [Fontlab](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab/). If anyone else ends up follow my footsteps. once you finish editing:

1. change the font name unless you want to overwrite the existing font (wouldn't recommend)
2. EXPORT AS TTF

I don't know why but when exporting as otf, the console shows the wrong characters.

Answer (score 4):

Although Unicode is a standard, not all glyphs are supported by all fonts.

For example, the glyph "▅" at code point U+2585 (Lower five eighths block) is not present in majority of Windows console fonts (like Consolas, Courier New, Lucida Console). See also: [Why isn't there a font that contains all Unicode glyphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732718/why-isnt-there-a-font-that-contains-all-unicode-glyphs)

You could instead configure your console to use either MS Gothic or NNimSun font. However, be prepared for other oddities then (for example, it seems MS Gothic displays a yen sign "¥" instead of a backslash "\", see: [Why is Windows 10 displaying \ ‎as ‎¥ on the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%C2%A5-on-the-command-line)).

Comment: This "not all glyphs are present in all fonts" is supposed to be handled via font fallback, however even the new Windows Terminal doesn't (yet) support it.  Very relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2664

Comment: Would there be any way to force to be a different font on start up so the program is portable and doesn't require the user to set anything up

Comment: @Noscka [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex)